# Is there a way to populate a full matrix given only an octant segment, with symmetry?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an octant of a symmetric matrix which looks like this:

```py
arr_in = [[1],
           [0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I need to convert this into the full array, is there a way to do this with numpy? The full matrix end product should be:

```py
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: What format is this in? Is it just a nested list (e.g., `[[1],[0,0],[0,0,1],...]`) or something else?

Comment: It's a nested list - I've updated the question, thank you!

Comment: There's a set of `np.tri...` functions that define the indices for upper and lower triangles.  You could probably use a couple of calls to one of those.

Comment: Not clear to me how the other *three* quarters shall look like. I.e., what your desired whole matrix is.

Comment: I've added in what the full matrix output I want to get it.

Comment: Apologies, it's also an octant not a quarter, which may have caused confusion.

Comment: Break the task into smaller pieces.  Looks like you could make a square with two of these triangles, and then combine 4 squares into the one big one.

Comment: @UnaDavies have either of our answers helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `np.clip` and `np.rot90`:

```py
import numpy as np


arr_in = [[1],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]

x = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype="uint8")

for idx, row in enumerate(arr_in):
    x[idx, :len(row)] = row

np.clip(x + x.T, 0, 1, out=x)

final = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype="uint8")
final[:5, :5] = np.rot90(x, 2)  # NW corner
final[:5, 4:] = np.rot90(x, 1)  # NE corner
final[4:, :5] = np.rot90(x, 3)  # SW corner
final[4:, 4:] = x               # SE corner
```

Output:

```py
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the triangle in a square numpy array.
Reflect that in the diagonal.
Place the result in a bigger numpy array.
Reflect that horizontally then vertically.

```
import numpy as np

arr_in = [[1], 
          [0, 0], 
          [0, 0, 1], 
          [0, 0, 0, 0], 
          [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]                                              

l = len( arr_in )                                                       

arr = np.zeros( (l,l), dtype = np.int64 )                               

# Generate square numpy array.  There may be a neater way to do this.
for row, a in enumerate(arr_in): 
    arr[ row, :len(a) ] = a 

arr
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

tr = np.tril( arr, -1 )   # Lower triangle, missing the diagonal ( -1 )

tr 
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

arr += tr.T   # arr += transpose of tr

arr  
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])


result = np.zeros( (9,9), dtype = np.int64 )  # Create result array

result[ 4:, 4:] = arr   # Fill the lower RH square

result 
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

result[ :4 ] = result[ 5:][::-1]  # Reflect in horizontal mirror

result                                                                 

# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

result[ :, :4 ] = result[ :, 5: ][:, ::-1]  # Reflect in vertical mirror                      

result                                                                 
# array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```